# Python Beautiful Soup search for elements that contain text from list

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Suppose I have a list of keywords, i.e. `["apple", "dog", "cat"]`, and some HTML. I'd like to return all the elements that contain one of these keywords as its immediate descendant. How would I go about doing this?

I've tried using `soup.find_all(text=keywords)`, but that yields nothing.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

source = """
<html>
    <p>I like apples</p>
    <p>I don't want to match this</p>
    <div>Dogs are cool. I don't match this either.</div>
    <div>I have a cat.</div>
</html>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "html.parser")
keywords = ["apple", "dog", "cat"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BeautifulSoup supports `regex` for text searching, so you can utilize that with the `IGNORECASE` flag (since your keyword is `dog`, and your element contains `Dogs`)

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

source = """
<html>
    <p>I like apples</p>
    <p>I don't want to match this</p>
    <div>Dogs are cool. I don't match this either.</div>
    <div>I have a cat.</div>
</html>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "html.parser")
keywords = ["apple", "dog", "cat"]

print(soup.find_all(text=re.compile("|".join(keywords), flags=re.IGNORECASE)))


>>>> ['I like apples', "Dogs are cool. I don't match this either.", 'I have a cat.']
```

As a note, you say "immediate descendant" and the element with `dogs` has "I don't match this either". Due to how your HTML is formatted, it will pick this up. If this line was something like `<div>Dogs are cool. <div>I don't match this either.</div></div>`, then the output would be

> ['I like apples', 'Dogs are cool. ', 'I have a cat.']